# Visual Studio Code will not compile to Unity despite no debugging errors (C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am a novice to game development so I am following a space shooter unity tutorial. However, after copying the code for player movement completely to the word my code still doesn't compile, despite no errors showing. If possible could someone check my code and see if I have missed an error, if not what can I do to make my code compile?

Code:

```cs
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class Boundary {
    public float xMin,
    xMax,
    zMin,
    zMax;
}

public class PlayerController: MonoBehaviour {
    public float speed;
    public float tilt;
    public Boundary boundary;

    private Rigidbody rb;
    void Start() {
        rb = GetComponent < Rigidbody > ();
    }

    void FixedUpdate() {
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);
        rb.velocity = movement * speed;

        rb.position = new Vector3(
        Mathf.Clamp(rb.position.x, boundary.xMin, boundary.xMax), 0.0f, Mathf.Clamp(rb.position.z, boundary.zMin, boundary.zMax));

        rb.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0.0f, 0.0f, rb.velocity.x * -tilt);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you attach the code to your player in the Editor? What do you mean it does not compile? You mean nothing happens and your player does not move?

Comment: @karel I copied and paste the code and it gets executed the way it is. I think it is not related to `using System`.

Comment: how do you mean "it gets executed the way it is"?

Comment: I meant the code gets executed without changing anything just copying and pasting.

Comment: What makes you think it does not compile?

Comment: it really isnt clear what problem you are having from your description - if the code is running, then its good - compiling it depends on what you're asking it, example: I have a scene I can run it in unity editor with ctrl+P, but I cant compile it because of fips on my PC.  But I also get an error.  What exactly are you doing can you give us a [mcve] walk through on how to recreate this lack of compile include all steps

Comment: I have created a player object (space ship) that needs to move forward and back using the keys within a boundary. I created a new script component and wrote the code via Unity. Once I completed my code and saved it, it gives me the message 'Please fix any compile errors and assign a valid script'. Thank you for your help, sorry for being vague.

Comment: Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

Unity compiles your code automatically every time that you enter to the editor, if there is some syntax error unity notifies you.

You should try to use Visual Studio instead of Visual Studio Code, in VS already has an addon to attach with Unity and debug your code.

Comment: I see the 'attach to Unity' function, I will use that to try and debug my code, thank you.